# How to search for a pattern in Vim

Tags: regex, vim

I am trying to search for all the strings following a pattern in a file that I have opened with gvim.

The pattern that I want to match is-

```
T0: {any_string1}_{anystring2}_{anystring3}:
```

where there can be any no of such "anystrings" in the pattern(which means there can be such 4 strings in the same pattern or may be 5 strings which is not fixed) and also those strings can be anything. Can somebody please tell me how to search for lines satisfying the above string pattern in gvim

Answer (score 0):

Press ***esc*** key and type ***/***.Then do this:

```
T0: \({\S\+\}_\?\)/+\:
```

Comment: The {3} quantifier will match only exactly 3 and it seem it's wanted one or more. Also, it seem that there are typos in your answer.

Comment: I am sure there is no typo with my latest answer because I posted it only after verifying several times. And coming to the quantifier, she said she needs to find `T0: {any_string1}_{anystring2}_{anystring3}:`. There are three strings and that's why I have included the quantifier.

Comment: I might have misunderstood the question, but she said that the number of strings is not fixed.
I thought there were typos because you escaped the closing braces but did not escape the opening in capturing group and did it the other way around in the quantifier.

Comment: When I tried to escape the open brace I got an error. And reg. the quantifier, I'll correct it now. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: And this is the error i get `E866: (NFA regexp) Misplaced {
E64: \{ follows nothing`

Answer (score 0):

You can construct the [search-pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#search-pattern) with these items:

- [`.`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/.): any single character
- [`*`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/star): 0 or more matches of the preceding
- `.*`: your "anystring" which *can be anything*, including nothing
- [`\(…\)`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C(): grouping

So, your *pattern* with *any no* (I assume at least one) *of such "anystrings"* is matched by

```
T0: {.*}\(_{.*}\)*:
```

Comment: Won't .*  match greedily?

Comment: @ndvo - That's right, it will match greedily - but as far as I can see, this won't prevent the pattern the querist wants to match from being matched. Of course, if the requirements were defined more strictly than as _anything_, the greediness may well become important.